# How to check free size in SharePoint Foundation with SQL express 2008

Tags: sql-server-express, space, sharepointfoundation2010

I have SharePoint Foundation installed.
Also I have install SQL express 2008.
I had 4 GB limit.
After some time I have spent almoust all free space.

Next, I have install SQL express 2008 R2 (R2 should give me 10 GB limit for database).
I want to check if everything is ok, but I do not know where to check free size.

I can check how much I have spent, but I can not check how much space I still have.

Can someone help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check the database size limit directly, however the version of SQL Server Express determines the limit. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express or newer will allow up to 10 GB of database size, while earlier versions allow only 4 GB.

If you are still in doubt, and want to confirm your instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express allows 10 GB databases, just create a new database and insert a bunch of data into it.